# shutdown: Kernel Panic; error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.20

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, shutdown, shared-library, hang

### System Information

System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-92-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7  Distro: Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

---

I am getting the following error. I tried to troubleshoot as follows, but I don't know what to do to resolve it. Any suggestions?

### Error

[image]

```
$ apt-file search libgcrypt.so.20
libgcrypt20: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
libgcrypt20: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.2.5

$ sudo apt install  libgcrypt20
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcrypt20 is already the newest version (1.8.5-5ubuntu1.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 23 not to upgrade.
```

```
$ sudo find /usr -name libgcrypt.so.20
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20

$ ldd /usr/bin/systemd-machine-id-setup
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff069d8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f00acfd2000)
        libsystemd-shared-245.so => /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so (0x00007f00acd78000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f00ad1f0000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f00acd6d000)
        libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f00acd16000)
        libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f00acd0d000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f00accd2000)
        libcryptsetup.so.12 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.12 (0x00007f00acc60000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f00acb42000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f00acb21000)
        libip4tc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libip4tc.so.2 (0x00007f00acb17000)
        libkmod.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmod.so.2 (0x00007f00acafc000)
        liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f00acadb000)
        libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f00aca79000)
        libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007f00aca67000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f00aca5c000)
        libseccomp.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2 (0x00007f00aca3a000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f00aca0f000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f00ac9e6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f00ac9c1000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f00ac9b8000)
        libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 (0x00007f00ac94d000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f00ac677000)
        libargon2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libargon2.so.1 (0x00007f00ac66d000)
        libjson-c.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.4 (0x00007f00ac659000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f00ac636000)
        libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f00ac4b4000)
        libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007f00ac488000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f00ac482000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f00ac3f0000)
        libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f00ac3c3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f00ac274000)
        libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007f00ac26c000)
```

---

@Aviro:

```
$ df /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        98G   23G   71G  24% /
/dev/sda2        98G   23G   71G  24% /
/dev/sda2        98G   23G   71G  24% /
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with libgcrypt, but that the system has not been signalled to switch the power off, or has failed to do so. It would seem that `shutdown` is still running, but the file systems have been unmounted.

Comment: @Bib Could you please elaborate, as in the attached image it shows "Reached target Power Off". Also, what should be done?

Comment: Is it possible that the folders where `libgcrypt.so.20` is located at are on separated filesystem (ie, not on the root filesystem)? Please show the output the following command: `df /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20`

Comment: @aviro please see the edit

Comment: Check if those files are readable. see that you can `cat` them (to another file) with no errors, or run `md5sum /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20` and verify toy don't have an error. You can try to use [`debsums`](https://www.tecmint.com/check-verify-md5sum-packages-files-in-linux/) to check the validity of the checksums of the libgcrypt20 package.

Comment: Last thing, please also check `ldd /usr/bin/systemctl |grep libgcrypt`.

Comment: @aviro The problem resolved after some tinkering I am not sure what exactly solved it.